# complex eigenvalues in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, eigenvector, eigenvalue

Any way of computing in opencv the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of an asymmetric matrix?

Comment: see this thread http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/Finding-Eigenvector-of-an-asymmetric-matrix-in-openCV-td2935398.html

Comment: @MoatazElmasry: You could put your comment as an answer, may be with some more explanation and links.

Comment: yaho I know, but since I'm not sure this is an actual answer and whether it works etc.. I decided to make it a comment

Comment: Ok so SVD won't do the trick, looks like there's no out of the box method in opencv
check question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574623/c-face-detection-recognition-implementations
especially the second answer. The guy offers on his blog an implementation based on opencv api to solve the problem. maybe you can follow it through from there