# Eigenvectors of non-symmetric matrix

Tags: opencv

I am trying to calculate eigenvectors of a non-symmetric matrix. I used decomposition.hpp header file from

> https://github.com/bytefish/opencv/blob/master/lda/include/decomposition.hpp

This is how I am calculating:

```
Mat m1=(Mat_<int>(2,2)<<2,7,-1,-6);
Mat evec, eval;
EigenvalueDecomposition eig(m1);
eval=eig.eigenvalues();
evec=eig.eigenvectors();
```

It gives me the correct eigenvalues, but not the correct eigenvectors. 
Obtained Results:

```
eval = [1, -5] 

evec = [0.9899494936611665, -1.178511301977579; 
       -0.1414213562373095, 1.178511301977579]
```

Expected Results:

```
eval = [1, -5] evec = [-7, 1;-1, 1]
```

Comment: OpenCV `cv::eigen` function assumes symmetrical matrices. Maybe decomposition.hpp assumes that too? Did you try something better known like `eigen3 lib`? http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page

Comment: I followed this answer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11344931/complex-eigenvalues-in-opencv                                                                                       It clearly states for non-symmetric matrices.

Comment: please add the results of `EigenvalueDecomposition` to your question and please add the right/expected results, too.

Comment: in fact the eigenvectors are just a scaled version of the right value. Eigenvectors aren't unique, so the solution is ok. Just scale the first eigenvector with: `(1.0)/(-0.1414213562373095)` and the second one with `1.0/1.178511301977579` please read about eigenvectors... or dont scale it, because it doesn't matter: each scale of an eigenvector is an eigenvector for the same eigenvalue afair.